# Nameerror: "name: "word" is not defined"

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a Pig latin translator and have run into the following error:

```
line 37, in <module>
    for i in word:
NameError: name 'word' is not defined
```

when I try to run this program.

Here is the relevant code:

```
def Pig_word0 (word): 
    "" "This is a function which can make string translate to pig latin and first letter become capital." "" 
# Determined string include a, e, i, o, u or not 
Prefix = [] 
for i in word: 
    if i in "aeiouy":
        break 
else: 
    Prefix.append (i)
```

Any tips appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: @andy your edit is not good, indentation was the actual problem.

Comment: indentation? spaces vs tabs?

Comment: @MarounMaroun, my fault. I've rolled back my edit

Comment: Your method is empty. Outside it `word` is unknown. Indent your code and you should be fine.

Comment: Please don't `for i in word` -- `i` is conventional for a meaningless integer value in a counting loop. I think you mean `for letter in word` or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

the problem here is, the interpreter assuming your code as two separate blocks

1) def Pig_word0 (word): 
    "" "This is a function which can make string translate to pig latin and first letter become capital." ""

2)

```
# Determined string include a, e, i, o, u or not <br/>
  Prefix = [] 
  for i in word: 
      if i in "aeiou":
          break 
      else: 
          Prefix.append (i)
```

so, properly indent the code and check